# How to increase throughput for Docker client pull?

Tags: docker, performance, docker-pull

I need Docker pull to be as fast as possible. I'm using an EC2 machine to pull a ~13.2GB from ECR (Amazon container registry) in about 3m10sec (70MB/sec).

**Can I tune the Docker client use more system resources (threads, connections) for the pull to complete faster**?
For example: can I tune Docker to download more layers in parallel? and/or multi-part download?

Notes:

1. I can't change the image itself.
2. CPU/Disk/Network are idle - There's enough network bandwidth between the client and the docker registry (both in AWS). There's enough disk IO (using SSD). There's enough CPU cores to spare.
3. I assume the repository server can support more connections.
4. I see the pull involves: 1/network transfer (Network+disk) 2/extracting the layers (CPU+disk)

Comment: I love this. It is very critical problem for me. Yet its hard to find any good solutions.
I was trying to do tarball docker images over http as alternative - its faster, but you have to step away from regular client flow... which is messy long term. 

I think it would be good if we could have uncompressed images (docker registry).